# When I enter a negative number it prints 'sorry' not the absolute number, what a I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def function_1():
    var_1 = input('''Enter any number''')
    if type(var_1) == int:
        print (abs(var_1))
    else:
        print ('''sorry''')

function_1()
```

When I enter in a negative number it prints the else statement 'sorry' instead of giving me the absolute number

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3, `input()` returns always a string.

In Python 2 `input()` evaluates the text as a Python expression, and `raw_input()` returns a string, this behavior is error prone as the most intuitive input mode can introduce different errors and unexpected behaviors. For that reason in Python 3 `input()` behaves like `raw_input()` does in Python 2.

You can convert the input to `int` with:

```
var_1 = int(input())
```